# Microsoft SQL Server 2005 backup the database in *.sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I work in a small company which is running M/S SQL Server 2005
Now our head office is asking me to give the whole database backup with the table schema in a single file of *.sql

please help me to backup my database in a *.sql including the table schema.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use SQL Server Management Studio

1. right click on your database and choose `Generate scripts...` and hit `Next`
2. choose `Script entire database and all database objects` and hit `Next`
3. choose `Save to file` and enter a path and a file name for your future sql script file. On the same screen choose `Advanced` and change the `Types of data to script` property value from `Schema only` to `Schema and data`. Hit `OK`. Hit `Next`.
4. and hit `Next` again.

*You can [download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062), install, and use SQL Server Management Studio that comes free with Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Express* for that

Answer (score 1):

I would go out and download Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8961

It is free.  You will be able to connect to the database, drill down into Databases, right click and under Tasks, pick Backup Database.  Make sure you pick full...CHoose Disk as the place you want to write it to and Execute...Look thru your options as well...

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I try it and it backup in a *.mdf but I want to backup it ina *.sql including the table schema

Comment: You might want to talk to your parent company and see what they will be using to import it.  Using my steps above will give you a complete backup of the database.  They would be able to import it and see exactly what you see.  You can name this file with any extension you want.  Finding out what they are really looking for might be a great place to start.

Answer (score 0):

I’d go with the method peterm suggested but note that this also has flaws. Problem is that SSMS doesn’t order the scripts in correct execution order.

For example, it might happen that DDL for stored procedure P is before DDL for table T that is used in P.

All you need to do is to review your script and make sure there are no such cases.  If there are you can try fixing this yourself or using some third party tool to generate script that is ordered correctly.